# Calling php class function in javascript (ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, class

I was wondering if is there any good practices to call method from php class with Javascript, by the way of Ajax.

This is my current "style" to execute it.

(The method in the class are only here for example)

PHP side :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] != null)
{
    extract($_POST);

    if($action)
    {
        $ajaxCommand = new EleveUpdate();

        if(method_exists($ajaxCommand, $action))
        {
            $reponse = call_user_func(array($ajaxCommand, $action),$_POST);
            echo $reponse;
            exit(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Cette méthode n'existe pas");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Cette action n\'est pas autorisée';
    return false;
}

class EleveUpdate
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function testfunct($data)
    {
        echo $data['eleve'];
    }
}
```

Javascript side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'eleveupdate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          action: "testfunct",
          eleve: 1
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            loading(true);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('error');
        },
        success: function(data) 
        {
            loading(false);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the isset $_POST is always in my class, I'm pretty sure this is not the right way to do it so, I'm here to found help about it.

Thanks you in advance

Simon

Comment: What do you think it should happen, and what happens instead? Moreover, try to move the class declaration on top.

Comment: The idea is to have a more "elegant" way to do it. This method works perfectly but, I don't know if I want to use it with like that. Everything is returned like I want but I want to find the "good practice" way :)

Comment: The only 'problem' I see is that someone can call an arbitrary method of your class from outside. If your class only contains 'safe' methods, there is no issue with that. Moreover, I don't like the use of extract() for $_POST variables.

Comment: Is that a "bad way" to use extract in that case ? (This is for my own information :))

Comment: Imagine a scenario where you use a variable to mean someone has special abilities like 'admin' and your code was saying if ($admin == true) blah blah.  By using extract() someone could put admin=1 in the AJAX call and become an admin because extract took the value from the URL and replaced a local variable with it.

Comment: @Simon : Crossphire Development shares my same point

Comment: Now I know why I don't have to use it ! Thanks you for this great advice. I'm going to use a token system to prevent using ajax call of function from outside the pages. Thanks you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's not easy to call scope-namings based on a string-request.
You can use something called LAMBDA, or anonymous functions. This way you can store an array of strings with a LAMBDA attached to them. Like this:

```
<?php
class EleveUpdate {
    private $funcs = array();

    function __construct($which_function) {
        $funcs['testfunct'] = create_function('$a,$b', 'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);');

        $funcs[$which_function];
    }
}
?>
```

See more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

You probably won't even need the Class anymore with this method, but just showing.